# I am trying to delete duplicates from a linked list, however the duplicates are still remaining

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dictionary, linked-list

I have the following class ListNode

```
class ListNode {
    constructor(val) {
        this.val = val
        this.next = null
    }
}
```

I am trying to delete repeat values by storing the values in a hash, and if those values are present, then the new Node should not be formed with those values; however, all I am accomplishing is a copy of the present list.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong within my hash.  Am I structuring the logic incorrectly?

```
const deleteDuplicates = (head) => {
    let newNode = new ListNode('dummy')
    let current = newNode
    let headHash = {}

    while (head) {
        if (headHash[head.val] === undefined) {
            if (newNode.next === null) newNode.next = new ListNode(head.val)
            else {
                newNode = newNode.next
                newNode.next = new ListNode(head.val)
            }
        }
        headHash = (headHash[head.val] || 0) + 1
        console.log(headHash, head.val);
        head = head.next

    }
    return current.next
}

const l = new ListNode(1)
l.next = new ListNode(1)
l.next.next = new ListNode(2)

const l2 = new ListNode(1)
l2.next = new ListNode(1)
l2.next.next = new ListNode(2)
l2.next.next.next = new ListNode(3)
l2.next.next.next.next = new ListNode(3)


console.log(deleteDuplicates(l));
console.log(deleteDuplicates(l2));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offending line seems to be this one:

`headHash = (headHash[head.val] || 0) + 1`

Instead of assigning the whole `headHash` to a value, you'll have to assign the `headHash`'s current head value property to a not undefined value. See the code below:

```js
class ListNode {
  constructor(val) {
    this.val = val;
    this.next = null;
  }
}
const deleteDuplicates = (head) => {
  let newNode = new ListNode("dummy");
  let current = newNode;
  let headHash = {};

  while (head) {
    if (headHash[head.val] === undefined) {
      if (newNode.next === null) {
          newNode.next = new ListNode(head.val);
      } else {
          newNode = newNode.next;
          newNode.next = new ListNode(head.val);
        }
    }
    // headHash = (headHash[head.val] || 0) + 1 // <- offending line
    headHash[head.val] = (headHash[head.val] || 0) + 1; // You need to assign the value to the headHash's key, not to the headHasn itself.
    head = head.next;
  }
  return current.next;
};

const l = new ListNode(1);
l.next = new ListNode(1);
l.next.next = new ListNode(2);

const l2 = new ListNode(1);
l2.next = new ListNode(1);
l2.next.next = new ListNode(2);
l2.next.next.next = new ListNode(3);
l2.next.next.next.next = new ListNode(3);



console.log(deleteDuplicates(l));
console.log(deleteDuplicates(l2));
```

Comment: That line should be `headHash = (headHash[head.val] || 0) + 1`
I am trying to store the values of the current node, if that value exists then that node should not be appended to the newNode, if it doesn't exist, as I believe that's what I am storing in the hash, it should be added.

Comment: You're assigning the whole headHash to a value, you'll have to assign the current node to the hash's property of the current head value. If you run the snippet you'll see that the duplicate list nodes are removed.

Comment: I am trying to do this 
if I have:
`Input: 1->1->2->3->3`

my headhash should look like this:

`headhash={1: 2, 2:1,3:2}`

Comment: Then when I look up `headHash[1]` it will not equal undefined and hence no newNode will be set up for that value.

Comment: yes the function is remove duplicates, that is how I am trying to return the node with removed values.  I am not aware of the logic to do this in place.

Comment: My answer above removes the duplicates, I'm not sure anymore what you're asking.

Comment: Ahh. I didn't realize that you solved it, I thought you were asking what my logic was for the hash.  I didn't think of adding the node itself to the hash.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're welcome! Sorry, I didn't realize you didn't realize I had posted a solution, yes, the issue was that you were not making use of the hash, you were assigning the literal values to it rather than assigning a property of the hash with the value as key.